# Stack Snippets broken — Insert Into Post doesn't work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Does the snippet tool no longer works? "Insert into Post" seems to do absolutely nothing, and I could not find a stack-trace in the console either.

Observed on

- Chrome version 40.0.2174.0 canary
- Safari 7

Update:
[SO is impacted as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272736/cannot-create-stack-snippet)

[Central bug tracker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240486/snippets-editor-wont-insert-and-close-on-so)

```html
<b>It works if you click outside of the snippet editor</b>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Haney's back from vacation. See [his answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240709/134069), he's patched the issue and the fix will be live in the next production release (meta: > rev 2014.10.7.2635, q&a: > rev 2014.10.7.1918).